# Wildcard a href id with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of links as so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link01">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="link02">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" id="link03">CNN</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="link04">Facebook</a>
```

Is it possible with jquery to have it execute a function if anything with an id of linkXX is clicked and then shuttle you over to the link target?   The links themselves will be variable in number, target and id name, the only unifying feature is that the id will always have the words 'link' followed by 2 numbers.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements which have an id that starts with "link"

```
$('a[id^="link"]').click(function(e){
  // your actions
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/jjsRF/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this by the `id` attribute, it's much easier to add a class to all of them and bind your event to the class.

```
<a class="someclass" href="http://www.google.com" id="link01">Google</a>
<a class="someclass" href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="link02">Yahoo</a>
<a class="someclass" href="http://www.cnn.com" id="link03">CNN</a>
<a class="someclass" href="http://www.facebook.com" id="link04">Facebook</a>

$(".someclass").click(function() {
  // your click handler
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use retrieved address in any way you like:

```
$('a[id^="link"]').click(function() {
     var address = $(this).attr("href");
     // do something with address
 });
```